# How to only execute IF statement if given an argument

Tags: python, if-statement, argparse, python-3.6

I have a piece of code which when run through the terminal works fine when it is provided with all the arguments, however I would like one argument to be optional, and to only run the IF statement if this argument is provided, here is my code:

```
import argparse
import sys
import csv 

parser= argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-r', '--range', help= 'Enter range of two m/z values in format of x,y', default= '1000,1500')
parser.add_argument('files', nargs= '*')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--amino_acid', help= 'Enter one letter code of amino acid you wish to search for (optional)')
args=parser.parse_args()



if aa in sequence:
                amino_acids.append(str(sequence))
```

So I would like the "if aa in sequence" part to only execute if the -a arg is given, however when this argument isn't given it tries to run it anyway and fails. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project2.py", line 32, in <module>
    if aa in sequence:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType
```

Comment: simplify your problem please and post only the bare minimum so as to make it understandable

Comment: `if aa in sequence:` is probably false when `-a` isn't set since `aa` is then `None`, so what's the real issue? please post the traceback of your error. "it fails" is just not enough

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I posted the error, I would like the IF statement to just be ignored if -a isn't provided

Comment: Instructions unclear... Neither `aa` nor `sequence` are defined.

Comment: `sequence` seemed to be the result of a `split` so for me it was a list. Now it's clear that it's a string.

Comment: @Faibbus I removed that bit to try and make it clearer, the only issue is the IF statement still executing even with no -a variable

Comment: The default for `-a` is `None`.  Your `if` testing needs to take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

```
if aa in sequence:
```

since you didn't provide `aa` as argument and `sequence` is a `str` (would have worked with a `list`) `in` complains.

Demo:

```
>>> None in []
False
>>> None in ""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType
>>>
```

So just fix it with:

```
if aa and aa in sequence:
```

or (explicit `None` test):

```
if aa is not None aa in sequence:
```

so if `aa` is empty/`None` the second condition isn't executed